# How to implement probability as a percentage

Tags: kotlin, probability

How to implement, what would a certain code be executed with a probability in percent?

Example: print hello not 100 times but with a probability of 20 percent.

```
repeat(100) {
    println("Hello - $it")
}
```

---

Comment: `if(Random.nextFloat() < .2f) println(whatever)`

Answer (score -2):

We choose a random number from 1 to 100 (since we need percentages from 1 to 100), if the number is in the range from 1 to the specified percentage (that is, it is simply less than this percentage), the probability comes true, if not (the random number is greater than the specified percentage), then it does not comes true.

```
fun probability(percent: Int, block: () -> Unit = {}): Boolean {

    val randomNum = (1..100).random()

    return if (randomNum <= percent) {
        block()
        true
    } else false
}
```

---

### USAGE:

---

```
repeat(100) {
    probability(20) { println("Hello - $it") }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is more complex than it needs to be. Why not just generate a single random number instead of creating a whole list and picking from it? Also `probability` is poorly named, the name suggests it computes a probability or something. Maybe `runWithProbability` would be a bit clearer, but the OP doesn't mention the desire to create such function in the first place anyway.